# Algoritmo de ordenamiento

Tags: java, array, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Estoy realizando un algoritmo que consta de 3 arreglos de una dimensión (o vectores): `nombre`, `identificacion` y `direccion`.

Ya le incorporé el algoritmo de ordenamiento mejor conocido como método de la burbuja. Con este ordené el arreglo `identificación`, pero quiero que al ordenarse estos, los arreglos `nombre` y `direccion` se ordenen también de acuerdo al cambio de posición de elementos de `identificación`.

Sé que es más fácil con clases, pero aun no me han enseñado eso y tengo que hacer un algoritmo con lo que nos ha enseñado el profesor de programación.

Este es el método que creé para llenar los vectores.

```
public static void llenar(String nom[], int cedu[], String direc[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nom.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("\nPor favor ingrese el nombre de la persona # " + (i + 1));
        nom[i] = ct.nextLine();
        nom[i] = nom[i].toUpperCase();

        System.out.println("\nPor favor ingrese la cedula de " + nom[i]);
        cedu[i] = cp.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nPor favor ingrese la dirección de residencia de " + nom[i]);
        direc[i] = ct.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Este es el método para el ordenamiento.

```
public static void burbuja(int vec[]) {

    int auxiliar;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < vec.length - i - 1; j++) {

            if (vec[j] > vec[j + 1]) {

                auxiliar = vec[j + 1];
                vec[j + 1] = vec[j];
                vec[j] = auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que al ordenar `identificacion` se ordenen también los otros 2 arreglos?

Comment: *Sé que es más fácil con clases, pero aun no me han enseñado eso y tengo que hacer un algoritmo con lo que nos ha enseñado el profesor de programación.* Al contrario, el profesor se pondra feliz que un estudiante se haya adelantado.. Hasta puntos extras podria dar (me ha pasado) :)

Answer (score 1):

Si bien denso ya respondió a la pregunta, daré otra solución al problema.

Puedes intercambiar los elementos de los otros vectores dentro del mismo bucle donde intercambias los enteros, de tal forma que quedan igualmente ordenados.

```
public static void burbuja(int[] vector, String[] vector2, String[] vector3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vector.length - i - 1; j++)
        {

            if (vec[j] > vec[j + 1])
            {
                // Se ordena el vector de enteros
                int auxiliar = vector[i];
                vector[i] = vector[j];
                vector[j] = auxiliar;

                // Se ordena el vector de cadenas
                String auxiliar = vector2[i];
                vector2[i] = vector2[j];
                vector2[j] = auxiliar;

                // Se ordena el segundo vector de cadenas
                auxiliar = vector3[i];
                vector3[i] = vector3[j];
                vector3[j] = auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, el código anterior es una primera versión que puede ser mejorada si utilizamos métodos parametrizados para hacer el intercambio de elementos dentro de los vectores.

Utilizaremos dos métodos para el intercambio de elementos en los vectores: uno para enteros y otro para cadenas (se puede hacer con un solo método de intercambio, pero por simplicidad no lo escribiré).

```
public static void intercambiarEnterosVector(int[] vector, int i, int j)
{
    int auxiliar = vector[i];
    vector[i] = vector[j];
    vector[j] = auxiliar;
}

// Innecesario cuando sepas más (herencia vs. genericidad)
public static void intercambiarCadenasVector(String[] vector, int i, int j)
{
    String auxiliar = vector[i];
    vector[i] = vector[j];
    vector[j] = auxiliar;
}
```

El código de ambos métodos es casi el mismo, pero por el momento te valdrá. Se puede encapsular el comportamiento de estos métodos en uno solo, con herencia o con genericidad, que aprenderás más adelante.

Ahora, en el bucle anidado haces los 3 intercambios llamando a los métodos corespondientes.

```
public static void burbuja(int[] vector, String[] vector2, String[] vector3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vector.length - i - 1; j++)
        {

            if (vec[j] > vec[j + 1])
            {
                intercambiarEnterosVector(vector, j, j + 1);
                intercambiarCadenasVector(vector2, j, j + 1);
                intercambiarCadenasVector(vector3, j, j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desde el `main` llamarías al método de ordenación (da igual si la primera o segunda versión) pasándole los vectores que quieras ordenar. Un ejemplo de cómo lo harías sería:

```
public class Ejemplo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] identificacion;
        String[] nombre;
        String[] direccion;

        // Creamos los vectores y los llenamos con datos

        burbuja(identificacion, nombre, direccion);
        // En este punto, tras la llamada, los tres vectores están ordenados
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces debo ordenar el vector int en el main para proceder a usar los metodos? Estoy un poco confundida

Comment: Los vectores se los pasas al método de burbuja, por lo que deben estar creados previamente, ya sea en el `main` o como variables globales. En el `main` solo harías la llamada al método de la burbuja nuevo, pero pasándole los tres vectores.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer para no ordenar utilizar 3 veces tu ordenamiento de burbuja es: puedes ordenar un arreglo que contenga indices, de modo que cuando quieras mostrar tus datos utilizas el arreglo de indices para iterar en tus 3 arreglos. EJEMPLO EN C++

```
void burbuja(int indices[], string parametro[], int size) {

    int auxiliar;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {

            if (parametro[indices[j]] > parametro[indices[j + 1]]) {

                auxiliar = indices[j + 1];
                indices[j + 1] = indices[j];
                indices[j] = auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso primero va el arreglo de indices y después el arreglo que utilizaras como parámetro para las comparaciones, en tu caso el de nombres. Ahora para mostrar los datos de los 3 arrelgos ordenados solo iteras en ellos con tu arreglo de indices. EJEMPLO EN C++

```
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << "Arreglos ordenados\n";
        cout << "NOMBRE:    " << nombre[indices[i]] << '\n';
        cout << "CEDULA:    " << cedu[indices[i]] << '\n';
        cout << "DIRECCION: " << nombre[indices[i]] << "\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: Denso no entiendo lo de los índices que me estás queriendo decir. Osea creo un nuevo array que sea índices pero cuál es la función de ese array?

Comment: @ValentinaGutierrez Lo que te está queriendo decir es que en vez de ordenar tu array de nombres, crees un array de enteros, tantos como nombres, y dentro le metas 0, 1, 2, 3, ... hasta la longitud. A la función de ordenar le pasas el array de enteros y el de nombres. La función ordena en función del array de nombres, pero no los mueve. Lo que mueve es el otro array, el de los enteros. Al salir de la función indices tendrá, por ejemplo 2, 0, 4, 1... Esto te dice que nombres[2] es el primero ordenado, y ese índice 2 te vale para ir a buscar la identificación y la dirección. Luego el 0, el 4...